# Show that $x_n$ does not converge weakly in $\ell_\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the sequence $x_n=(1,1,\dots, 1, 0,0,\dots)\in \ell_\infty$ whose the first $n$-coordinate are all $1$. Show that $x_n$ does not converge weakly in $\ell_\infty$.

I have no idea about the proof. It seems that we need to find one $f\in \ell^*$ so that $f(x_n)$ does not converge.

---

There is a hint to apply the following Lemma but I did not know how to do that.

> Let $x_n\to x$ weakly in a normed space. Then $x\in \overline{con(x_k)}$ (the smallest convex set containing $x_k$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

The only candidate for a weak limit of $x_n$ is the constant sequence
$$\mathbb{1}:k\mapsto 1$$

Show that the constant sequence $\mathbb{1}\notin\overline{\operatorname{co}(x_n)}$, where the closure is taken with respect to the norm $\|\;\|_\infty$-topology on $\ell_\infty$.

Observe that if $y\in\operatorname{co}(x_n:n\in\mathbb{N})$, then $0\leq y(m)\leq1$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$  and more importantly, $y(m)=0$ for all but finitely many $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Hence, $\|\mathbb{1}-y\|_\infty=1$.